# Unable to run my first wordcount example in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can anyone help me solve my this problem?
I am beginner to hadoop.

The steps I followed to run my program:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java 
sudo jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class
bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount myfileName outputFile
```

This is what I got when I try to run my program

```
abbas@abbas:~/hadoop-2.7.3$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
abbas@abbas:~/hadoop-2.7.3$ export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
abbas@abbas:~/hadoop-2.7.3$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
abbas@abbas:~/hadoop-2.7.3$ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java 
abbas@abbas:~/hadoop-2.7.3$ sudo jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class
abbas@abbas:~/hadoop-2.7.3$ bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount tempfile output8

17/06/09 02:20:24 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/06/09 02:20:25 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
17/06/09 02:20:26 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/abbas/.staging/job_1496953867826_0001

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/abbas/tempfile
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self explanatory.

> Input path does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/abbas/tempfile

Do you have an hdfs user directory?

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user | grep $(whoami)
```

Did you put any file named `tempfile` there?

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p "/user/$(whoami)"
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /path/to/tempfile "/user/$(whoami)"
```

---

It's worth pointing out that [the example *assumes* you have files in HDFS already](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Usage)